# How to make numpy load faster

Tags: python, numpy

I'd like to use numpy to make my program faster. The only part I want to use is string arrays. When I do

```
import numpy
```

it takes about 5 seconds to loop numpy, which is more time than the speedup I was looking to get for my normal program.

Is there a way to only load the string array part of numpy?

Comment: 5s is really long ... Did you try doing it a bunch of times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
from numpy import array
```

This *should* not be any faster as both ways import the entire module. I have no idea why it is in your case.

Comment: This still imports `numpy`, from what I remember.

Comment: I don't think this will help at all.  It still imports everything from `numpy/dir/__init__.py`.  That just controls what goes into your local namespace.

Comment: Thanks, that takes it down to loading in 0.2 seconds

Comment: @Blender,@mgilson you are both correct, however the OP reports a faster loading time. I've added a link to an SO answer with a deeper analysis of importing using the `dis` module. @Superdooperhero - When do you import? everything in this sounds absolutely strange.

Comment: @msvalkon -- That doesn't say anything about how long it takes to do the *import* though.  Only about efficiency of skipping an attribute access every time...

Answer (score -2):

I think that very not important if you import everything or just partial. What matters are efficient algorithms used and how you run the application. first, take a look on [Python speed](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed). Also try to use JIT compiler, like [PyPy](http://pypy.org/).

Comment: PyPy doesn't support Numpy yet.

Comment: It seems to supported it, see http://morepypy.blogspot.ro/2012/11/numpy-status-update-5.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883885/using-numpy-with-pypy